# Windows Phone set ringer to vibrate/silent and or not accept calls / hang up

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silent, vibration

Is there any way to programatically set a windows phone to not ring in any way? I know there was no method before mango but I could not find anything about if you are now able to or not. It is crucial that the GPS and or cellular connectivity stay on while the ringer is off.

The purpose of the app I would like to make is to switch the phone into a state where it makes no noise, not even from incoming calls, without the user having to manually change the setting.

Any work around is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible using the public WP7.1 APIs. The phone has been designed with security in mind, as a result there are limitations on what your application can do. Changing phone state or settings in any way that extends beyond the scope of your application are a security issue and as a result are not possible.